# VS C# code BindingNavigatorSaveItem saves new data to a temporary dataset but not to the permanent database with

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

My C# code saves new data to a temporary dataset but not to the permanent database. Below is my code:

public partial class AddProduct : Form

```
{
            private Database1DataSet db1ds = new Database1DataSet();

            public AddProduct()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   private void tblProductBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.tblProductBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.database1DataSet);
            MessageBox.Show("Update temporary database1DataSet Successful");

            this.tableAdapterManager.TblProductTableAdapter.Fill(this.db1ds.TblProduct);
            db1ds.TblProduct.AcceptChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Update db1ds Successful??");

            }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update Failed");
            ex.GetBaseException();

        }

        //Trying to get temporary database1DataSet saved to Permenant Database1DataSet
        //and eventually to the server database Database1
        this.tableAdapterManager.TblProductTableAdapter.Fill(this.db1ds.TblProduct);
        db1ds.TblProduct.AcceptChanges();

    }
```

How can I save changes permanently to the db1ds dataset or to the database?